# How to convert a JavaPairRDD to Dataset?

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

`SparkSession.createDataset()` only allows `List, RDD, or Seq` - but it doesn't support `JavaPairRDD`.

So if I have a `JavaPairRDD<String, User>` that I want to create a `Dataset` from, would a viable workround for the `SparkSession.createDataset()` limitation to create a wrapper `UserMap` class that contains two fields: `String` and `User`.

Then do `spark.createDataset(userMap, Encoders.bean(UserMap.class));`?

Answer (score 1):

If you can convert the `JavaPairRDD` to `List<Tuple2<K, V>>` then you can use createDataset method which takes List. See below sample code.

```
JavaPairRDD<String, User> pairRDD = ...;
Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataset(pairRDD.collect(), Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(),Encoders.bean(User.class))).toDF("key","value");
```

or you can convert to RDD

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataset(JavaPairRDD.toRDD(pairRDD), Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(),Encoders.bean(User.class))).toDF("key","value");
```

Comment: In my situation, I have lots of transformations to arrive at `JavaPairRdd<String,User> pairRDD...`. So if I call `pairRDD.collect()`, all the `Dataset` optimization will be lost.