# Spark convert PairRDD to data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I convert a pair RDD of the following type

```
joinResult
res16: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD[com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon,java.util.HashSet[com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon]] = org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD@264b550
```

to a data frame?
https://github.com/geoHeil/geoSparkScalaSample/blob/master/src/main/scala/myOrg/GeoSpark.scala#L72-L75

```
joinResult.toDF().show
```

will not work as well as

Comment: Have you seen if this works for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42405905/how-to-convert-a-javapairrdd-to-dataset

Comment: Is I possible without a collect?

Comment: you could use `pairRDD.rdd` instead

Comment: in your case `joinResult.rdd.toDF.show` should work

Comment: This is a step into the right direction, but will fail due to missing encoder.

Comment: Could you provide an encoder? What the exact error message about missing encoder?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The problem is outlined very well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-a-datase as shown https://github.com/geoHeil/geoSparkScalaSample/blob/master/src/main/scala/myOrg/GeoSpark.scala#L76-L77 will simply put all into a single binary column which destroys the possibility for joins. So far I did not get more complex stuff to work. Looking forward to contributions