# Spark custom encoder for dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, encoder

I know about [How to store custom objects in Dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-a-dataset) but still, it is not really clear for me how to build this **custom encoder which properly serializes to multiple fields.** Manually, I created some functions https://github.com/geoHeil/geoSparkScalaSample/blob/master/src/main/scala/myOrg/GeoSpark.scala#L122-L154 wich map a Polygon back and forth between `Dataset - RDD - Dataset` by mapping the objects to primitive types spark can handle i.e. a tuple `(String, Int)`(edit: full code below).

For example, to go from the Polygon Object to a tuple of `(String, Int)` I use the following

```
def writeSerializableWKT(iterator: Iterator[AnyRef]): Iterator[(String, Int)] = {
    val writer = new WKTWriter()
    iterator.flatMap(cur => {
      val cPoly = cur.asInstanceOf[Polygon]
      // TODO is it efficient to create this collection? Is this a proper iterator 2 iterator transformation?
      List(((writer.write(cPoly), cPoly.getUserData.asInstanceOf[Int])).iterator
    })
  }
 def createSpatialRDDFromLinestringDataSet(geoDataset: Dataset[WKTGeometryWithPayload]): RDD[Polygon] = {
    geoDataset.rdd.mapPartitions(iterator => {
      val reader = new WKTReader()
      iterator.flatMap(cur => {
        try {
          reader.read(cur.lineString) match {
            case p: Polygon => {
              val polygon = p.asInstanceOf[Polygon]
              polygon.setUserData(cur.payload)
              List(polygon).iterator
            }
            case _ => throw new NotImplementedError("Multipolygon or others not supported")
          }
        } catch {
          case e: ParseException =>
            logger.error("Could not parse")
            logger.error(e.getCause)
            logger.error(e.getMessage)
            None
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

I noticed that already I start to do a lot of work twice (see the link to both methods). Now wanting to be able to handle

https://github.com/geoHeil/geoSparkScalaSample/blob/master/src/main/scala (full code below)

```
/myOrg/GeoSpark.scala#L82-L84
 val joinResult = JoinQuery.SpatialJoinQuery(objectRDD, minimalPolygonCustom, true)
  //  joinResult.map()
  val joinResultCounted = JoinQuery.SpatialJoinQueryCountByKey(objectRDD, minimalPolygonCustom, true)
```

which is a `PairRDD[Polygon, HashSet[Polygon]]`, or respectively `PairRDD[Polygon, Int]` how would I need to specify my functions as an Encoder in order to not solve the same problem 2 more times?

Comment: Please don't post relevant code outside Stack Overflow. Links you provide are likely to become invalid (especially without hashes) rendering this useless for the future readers.

Comment: @zero323 I edited the code snippets to contain the full code. Thought it would be more readable. Please have a look at this edited version. For a better reference of the full context I would want to keep the links.

Comment: Thanks and please follow the guidelines in the future. Questions which depend on the external resources are as useless as link only answers and _and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_ is the official requirement. "Questions" like http://stackoverflow.com/q/42689512/1560062 to anyone but you. BTW I'd really recommend "permanent" links(with commit hash) if you share code in general. Regarding your question - great answer by [alec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3072788) you've already linked here is the only sensible option available out there right now.

Comment: What is unclear to me is how to register an Encoder based on my 2 methods which provide the serialization to a tuple of (string, int).

Comment: `(String, Int)` can use default `Product` `Encoder` and it is not clear what is the purpose of this code and why you need all these conversions in the first place. Parse once, serialize, and move on :)

Comment: Polygon doesn't support product. I  need to go from hive to spark rdd as only there some suitable indices exist. Then the joined result needs to be stored in hive.

Comment: So use generic (Kryo or Java) encoder. These conversions don't make much sense.

Comment: Maybe you are right. But will Hive be able to handle that when I persist this binary df as a hive table?

Comment: Kryo / Java enc output is just a byte array. It won't have any special meaning for Hive and is a valid type.